# Bootstrap- Row wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to give 6 col-md-4's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpVYl.jpg) in one row and they wrap themselves into two rows and working the same way while resizing and when I am trying to do the same with col-md-3 (by giving 8 of them) they causing a problem when resizing. Please help

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row first-row slides">
        
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 product-categories-item">
            <div>
                <a routerLink="/banners">                
                        <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_banners.png" alt="banners"> -->
                        <div>
                            <h3>Banners</h3>                       
                        </div>                
                </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3  product-categories-item">
                 <div>
                 <a routerLink="/flags">                    
                      <!--   <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_flag.png" alt="flag"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3 >Flags</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3  ">
            <div>
                <a routerLink="/retractable-banners">
                       <!--  <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_retractable.png" alt="Retractable Banners"> -->
                        <div>
                            <h3>Retractable Banners</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">
             <div>
                 <a routerLink="/signs">
                    
                       <!--  <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_signs.png" alt="Yard Signs"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3 >Yards Signs</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div> 
          
          
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">
            <div>
                <a routerLink="/banner-stands">                    
                       <!--  <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_stands.png" alt="Stands"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3 >Banner Stands</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">
            <div>
                 <a routerLink="/custom-table-throws">                    
                        <!-- <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_table.png" alt="table covers"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3 >Table Covers</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3  ">
            <div>
                 <a routerLink="/canvas-prints">                    
                       <!--  <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_canvas.png" alt="Canvas Prints"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3>Canvas Prints</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">
            <div>

                <a routerLink="/hardware-accessories">                    
                        <!-- <img class="img-responsive"  src="/assets/img/product-categories/cat_hardware.png" alt="hardware"> -->
                        <div >
                            <h3 >Hardware &amp; Accessories</h3>                       
                        </div>                    
                </a>
                </div>
            </div> 
                      
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the html code I have used which is causing the error. appreciate your help

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Posted the code .Please check

Comment: Having the same problem with Bootstrap 4 in Aug 2020. Did you find an answer?